# Problems with kickstart script, partition info crashes deployment

Tags: linux, centos, pxe-boot, kickstart, cobbler

Currently testing cobbler, but have problem with the kickstart script when the partition information is loaded.

Here is my ks:
http://pastebin.ca/1824343

I can't figure out what is the problem with the `part`section at all. Without it, it works. I've even tried `autopart`. If the entry is removed, it works, but of course I have to provide the installer with partition information.

Under the kickstart an python exception is raised. I get a Errno 2 No such file or directory. My Apache logs states:

> File does not exist: /var/www/cobbler/links/CentOS-5.3-x86_64/images/updates.img
>
> File does not exist: /var/www/cobbler/links/CentOS-5.3-x86_64/disc1
>
> File does not exist: /var/www/cobbler/links/CentOS-5.3-x86_64/images/product.img

But without the `part` information, no error occours.

What am I not seeing?

Cobbler 2.0.3, imported the CentOS 5.3 x86_64 DVD, PXE booting from a Xen guest.

Comment: I think maybe I've found the answer. The initrd.img which is loaded after the inital tftp transfer, contains the disc1 reference which gets logged in apache error_log. Seems like the CentOS DVD is merged from all the CD iso´s, and maybe someone forgot to remove some references.

I'll get back with more info :)

Comment: For other people, it might be related to cobbler issue #153 https://github.com/cobbler/cobbler/issues/153

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea why I didn't work, but I started from scratch and built cobbler up again and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for CentOS but Red Hat Enterprise Linux will display a message on Virtual Console 3 (VT3) if there is a partitioning issue. Is there such a message?